# Chart.js: Bar Chart Click Events

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've just started working with Chart.js, and I am getting very frustrated very quickly. I have my stacked bar chart working, but I can't get the click "events" to work.

I have found a [comment on GitHub by `nnnick`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/577#issuecomment-55897221) from Chart.js stating to use the function `getBarsAtEvent`, even though this function cannot be found in the [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options) at all (go ahead, do a search for it). The documentation does mention the `getElementsAtEvent` function of the `chart` reference, but that is for Line Charts only.

I set an event listener (the right way) on my canvas element:

```
canv.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
```

...yet in my `handleClick` function, `chart.getBarsAtEvent` is undefined!

Now, in the Chart.js document, there is a statement about a different way to register the click event for the bar chart. It is much different than `nnnick`'s comment on GitHub from 2 years ago.

In the [Global Chart Defaults](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) you can set an `onClick` function for your chart. I added an `onClick` function to my chart configuration, and it did nothing...

So, how the heck do I get the on-click-callback to work for my bar chart?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**P.S.:** I am not using the master build from GitHub. I tried, but it kept screaming that `require is undefined` and I was not ready to include CommonJS just so that I could use this chart library. I would rather write my own dang charts. Instead, I downloaded and am using the [**Standard Build**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/v2.0-dev/dist/Chart.js) version that I downloaded straight from the link at the top of the [documentation page](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

**EXAMPLE:** Here is an example of the configuration I am using:

```
var chart_config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: '#848484',
                data: [4, 2, 6]
            },
            {
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                backgroundColor: '#848484',
                data: [1, 6, 3]
            },
            {
                label: 'Dataset 3',
                backgroundColor: '#848484',
                data: [7, 5, 2]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Stacked Bars'
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true
                }
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true
                }
            ]
        },
        onClick: handleClick
    }
};
```

Comment: I found that I was able to have my `onClick` function called by setting `chart.config.options.onClick = handleClick` yet this does not help me find what part of my chart was clicked on. This basically is the same as setting my event listener on the `canvas` node myself.

Comment: It mentions `activeElements` being passed as the second argument to `onClick` in the `options` parameter to `new Chart()`.

Comment: @tscizzle Your link is broken

Comment: The link is actually this one: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/general/interactions/events.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I managed to find the answer to my question by looking through the [Chart.js source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/v2.0-dev/dist/Chart.js).

Provided at line 3727 of Chart.js, Standard Build, is the method `.getElementAtEvent`. This method returns me the "chart element" that was clicked on. There is sufficent data here to determine what data to show in a drill-down view of the dataset clicked on.

On the first index of the array returned by `chart.getElementAtEvent` is a value `_datasetIndex`. This value shows the index of the dataset that was clicked on.

The specific bar that was clicked on, I believe, is noted by the value `_index`. In my example in my question, `_index` would point to `One` in `chart_config.data.labels`.

My `handleClick` function now looks like this:

```
function handleClick(evt)
{
    var activeElement = chart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
```

..where `chart` is the reference of the chart created by chart.js when doing:

```
chart = new Chart(canv, chart_config);
```

The specific set of data that was selected by the click can therefore be found as:

```
chart_config.data.datasets[activeElement[0]._datasetIndex].data[activeElement[0]._index];
```

And there you have it. I now have a datapoint that I can build a query from to display the data of the bar that was clicked on.

**AUGUST 7TH, 2021. UPDATE**

There is now a method for what we are looking for. Take a look at [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition)

Comment: This is also what I've found after hours of (hopeless) searching in documentation.
But my problem is, that it returns me all the datasets, so `activeElement[0]._datasetIndex` is still the same - zero, no matter on which bar I click! `_index` is working. Haven't you had the same problem?

Comment: I have not encountered this problem @JánJanočko , but I haven't worked with Chart.js since this post. I need to take a look at it again, as I can see that there are some issues with the chart widget I created. I will keep you posted on my findings.

Comment: Thanks @WebWanderer. Getting that activeElement was the key. In my case I could just use the chart's `label` and then did a `switch()` on it. Then each `case "<myLabel>":` would do a certain thing, for me just go to a different web page: `window.location.href = "/myLabelPage";`.

Comment: Hi @JánJanočko , I'm also getting zero for activeElement[0]._datasetIndex , no matter on which bar I click. Did you find a way to get the exact clicked bar value?

Comment: Sorry for late response, @zlas, I had to look into my old scripts. I'm not sure how I did it, but this is my code: `var points = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);
     var dataset = myChart.getDatasetAtEvent(event);

     if (points[0]) {
      pt = points[0];
      dt = dataset[0];

      showDetailsFor(dt._datasetIndex, pt._index);
     }`
I think I somehow combined data from `getElementsAtEvent()` and `getDatasetAtEvent()` to get unique pair that clearly determines clicked bar and pass it to my own function `showDetailsFor()`. Sorry, I am totally out of context now.

Comment: Thanks @JánJanočko. I was able to find the issue with my code. Thanks again.

Comment: This is now documented in the API page! http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente

Comment: @Sebj Awesome! I'm glad to see that Chart.js has active support again. It has been a while since I checked it out. I will need to take a look again.

Comment: Setting the `onClick()` event handler blocks the ability to hide datasets by clicking their legends. Is there a way to call the default handler inside the custom `onClick()` handler?

Comment: Could you post the entire chart.js code with the event handler? Trying to figure out where to place all this.

Comment: @mikelowry This is really old, and likely very outdated for the most recent versions of Chart.js. I haven't looked at any of this in years, and I'm not even sure where this code is anymore.

Comment: If user clicks on the x axis label, then how to get the label value

Comment: With v3.9.1 there is a new function `getElementsAtEventForMode(...)`  see [Dev API Docu v3.9.1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition) or use the [latest](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/developers/api.html)

Comment: Could any of you tell me where exactly I would attach the handleClick function?  What line of code attaches the function to the chart?

Comment: @Hugobop in this example, the `handleClick` method is attached to the Chart.js canvas element, such as:

canv.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

This is mentioned in my original post.

This question is very outdated. Chart.js has since been re-adopted and developed on. At the time of writing, Chart.js was managed by a single developer that eventually abandoned the projects. I highly suggest checking the source of the latest Chart.js for your answers.

Answer (score 57):

Hi this is the click event under options which is getting values from x and y-axis

```
onClick: function(c,i) {
    e = i[0];
    console.log(e._index)
    var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
    var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
    console.log(x_value);
    console.log(y_value);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error as Cannot read property '0' of undefined for i

Comment: please post plunker

Comment: Simple and concise. Worked for me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! So you should just add this to `options`: `events: ['click'], onClick: function(c, i) {...`, and that function will be called *automagically*. Just add a validation for `e` not being undefined, otherwise if the user clicks too far from the bars it will throw an exception.

Comment: Maybe also `var y_value = this.data.datasets[e._datasetIndex].data[e._index];` just to not hardcode that dataset index

Comment: What is c in this function

Comment: I'm using React, this answer works for me.  I guess I just need to log the e for the onClick property. e has the information of which bar that I'm clicking.

Comment: @mikelowry, I have tried many times. I have no idea what c is, and c isn't used in that function. but that function won't work without the c. So I just left it there.

Comment: c is the click event, i is an array of active elements.

Answer (score 13):

I found this solution at https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/489

```
public chartClicked(e: any): void {
  if (e.active.length > 0) {
  const chart = e.active[0]._chart;
  const activePoints = chart.getElementAtEvent(e.event);
  if ( activePoints.length > 0) {
   // get the internal index of slice in pie chart
   const clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
   const label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementIndex];
   // get value by index
   const value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[clickedElementIndex];
   console.log(clickedElementIndex, label, value)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Chartjs V3.4.1**

This is what worked for me in v3, after looking at solutions for older versions:

```
const onClick = (event, clickedElements) => {
  if (clickedElements.length === 0) return

  const { dataIndex, raw } = clickedElements[0].element.$context
  const barLabel = event.chart.data.labels[dataIndex]
  ...
}
```

- `raw` is the value of the clicked bar.
- `barLabel` is the label of the clicked bar.

You need to pass the `onClick` to the bar chart config:

```
const barConfig = {
  ...
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    onClick,
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use onClick like this.

```
var worstCells3GBoxChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: lbls,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Worst Cells by 3G',
                        data: datas,
                        backgroundColor: getColorsUptoArray('bg', datas.length),
                        borderColor: getColorsUptoArray('br', datas.length),
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    onClick: function (e) {
                        debugger;
                        var activePointLabel = this.getElementsAtEvent(e)[0]._model.label;
                        alert(activePointLabel);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please explain the code inside the onClick function, as its not clear what you suggest to be the solution to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly an old question, but it rated highly in my 2023 search for "chart.js click events". So a post seemed worthwhile.

Hardly any of the posted answers work in version 4 of chart.js. For version 4 use getElementsAtEventForMode

```js
var chartStr = '{ "type": "bar","title": "hello title", "data": {"labels": ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],"datasets": [{ "label": "# of Votes", "data": [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3] , "backgroundColor":["Orange","255","#333333","#666666","#999999"] }] }, "options": {"indexAxis": "y","scales": {"y": {"beginAtZero": true, "ticks":{} } } } }'

const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart');
var chartObject = JSON.parse(chartStr);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx1, chartObject);
ctx1.onclick = function(evt) {
  var points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', {
    intersect: true
  }, true);
  if (points.length) {
    const firstPoint = points[0];
    const label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
    const value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
    alert(label);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

The way the chart.js team change/break the API between major versions is certainly bold, but it can unintentionally can make historical stackoverflow posts (that don't specify a chart.js version) misleading and of negative help value. This seems to be the case for virtually all chart.js community help I come across.

Comment: Thank you for providing an updated answer here. I am surprised by how often I still get questions on this very outdated post.

Comment: It's more flexible to use `evt.chart` instead `myChart` inside function.

Comment: I agree and I will try and never use ChartJS again after this project. It's highly likely some of the newer libraries that support composition are way better and not such an utter pain to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Well done! This seems to return the data value being charted though, which in many cases might be possible to appear more than once, thus making it unclear what was clicked on.

This will return the actual data label of the bar being clicked on. I found this more useful when drilling down into a category.

```
chart_config.data.labels[activeElement[0]._index]
```

Comment: This will not work if you do not have labels. You can have data specified in format `data: [{t:"2020-01-04 08:06Z", y:0},{t:"2020-01-04 08:07Z", y:45},{t:"2020-01-04 08:08Z", y:47}]`, and in this case, labels will not exists.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work in another way.
Might not be supported, but sometimes, I find that neither the label nor the value is adequate to get me the necessary information to populate a drill-through.

So what I did was add a custom set of attributes to the data:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("cnvMyChart").getContext("2d");
if(theChart != null) {theChart.destroy();}
theChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: typ,
data: {
labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
datakeys: ["thefirstone","thesecondone","thethirdone","thefourthone","thefifthone","thesixthone"],
datasets: [{
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
```

...etc

Then when I need to push the drillthrough key into another ajax call, I was able to get it with this:

```
var theDrillThroughKey = theChart.config.data.datakeys[activePoints[0]._index];
```

So I'm really not sure that it's appropriate to be adding custom elements into the data for the Chart, but it's working so far in Chrome, IE and Firefox. I needed to be able to put more information into the drillthrough than I really wanted displayed.

Example of the full thing: https://wa.rrdsb.com/chartExamples

Thoughts?

Comment: remove the getContext. `var ctx = document.getElementById("cnvMyChart").getContext("2d");`  try  `var ctx = document.getElementById("cnvMyChart");`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with multiple datasets, and used this workaround:

```
var clickOnChart = function(dataIndex){
    ...
}
var lastHoveredIndex = null;
var chart_options = {
    ...
    tooltips: {
        ...
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                var index = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;
                var value  = chart.datasets[index].data[0];
                var label  = chart.datasets[index].label;

                lastHoveredIndex = index;

                return value + "€";
            }
        }
    },
    onClick:function(e, items){
        if ( items.length == 0 ) return; //Clicked outside any bar.

        clickOnChart(lastHoveredIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good trick! Works really well for Stacked group chart. Thanks!

Comment: If user clicks on x axis label, then how to get the label?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you declared a chart using a method like so:

```
  window.myBar = new Chart({chart_name}, {
       type: xxx,
       data: xxx,
       events: ["click"],
       options: {
           ...
       }
  });
```

A good way of declaring onclick events would involve listening for the canvas click, like so:

```
({chart_name}.canvas).onclick = function(evt) {
     var activePoints = myBar.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
     // let's say you wanted to perform different actions based on label selected
     if (activePoints[0]._model.label == "label you are looking for") { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

****check below working code****

```html
<div class="nss_main_chart_box">
    <canvas id="myChartSite"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.chartColors = {
        lightpink: 'rgb(255, 136, 136)',
        yellow: 'rgb(255, 222, 121)',
        green: 'rgb(157, 223, 118)',
        orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
        grey: 'rgb(231,233,237)'
    };
    var myChartSite = document.getElementById("myChartSite").getContext('2d');
    Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); 
    var myChartOnSi = new Chart(myChartSite, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: ["Last month", "This month", "Next month"],  //here to set x-axis option
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'January',  //here to set top heading label name
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.lightpink, //here to set top heading label Color
                    data: ['150', '500', '300'], //here to set Y-axis dynamic data for chart

                },
                {
                    label: 'February',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                    data: ["70", "20", "130"],
                },
                {
                    label: 'March',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
                    data: [200, 90, 70],
                },
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    labels: {
                        value: {
                            color: 'blue'
                        }
                    },
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold',
                        size: 16
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text:"Month Data",
                    padding:{
                        left:0,
                        right:0,
                        bottom:0,
                        top:20
                    },
                },
            },
            onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
                event.native.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
            },
            onClick: (e, activeEls) =>{
                let datasetIndex = activeEls[0].datasetIndex;
                let dataIndex = activeEls[0].index;
                let datasetLabel = e.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
                let value = e.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];
                let label = e.chart.data.labels[dataIndex];
                var chartTitleText = e.chart.titleBlock.options.text;
                console.log('chartTitleText is ',chartTitleText,'Clicked:', datasetLabel, 'Value:', value,'label',label);

                },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        font: {
                            size: 16
                        }
                    },
                },
                y: {
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize : 5,
                        font: {
                            size: 16
                        }
                    },
                }
            }

        }
    }); 
});



</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: perfect answer. usually such comments are not encourage yet the community bot comment before mine was not as welcoming so I wanted to provide encouragement. i love that i can run this examples code snippet. i have been able to modify my chart to have an onclick very quickly with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the chart options for Chart.js v3.5.1 which is latest

Check below sample code

```
let enterpriseChartOptions = {
    responsive:true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    onClick: (c,i) => {
      console.log('Get the underlying label for click,', c.chart.config._config.data.labels[i[0].index]);
    },
    plugins: { 
      title:{
        text:'Enterprise Dashboard (Health Status of 10 stores) updated every 30 minutes',
        fontSize:20
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: true,
        type: 'category',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          padding: 8,
        },
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          callback: function(val, index) {
            // Show the label
            return val < 1 ? "All good" : (val < 2 && val >=1) ? "Warning": val === 2 ? "Critical" : ""; 
          },
          //color: 'red',
          stepSize: 1,
          padding: 8
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          top: 25,
          bottom: 0
      }
    },

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var employeeDetailsCtx = document.getElementById("employee-details").getContext("2d");

var employee_details_data = {
    labels: ["Late Present", "On Leave", "Training", "Tour"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Officer",
        backgroundColor: "#5A8DEE",
        data: [
            ...
        ]
    }, {
        label: "Staff",
        backgroundColor: "#4BC0C0",
        data: [
            ...
        ]
    }]
};

var myoption = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true
    },
    hover: {
        animationDuration: 1
    },
    onClick: function (evt, i) {
        var activePoint = employeeDetailsBarChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
        var data = activePoint._chart.data;
        var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
        var label = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
        var value = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[activePoint._index];
        e = i[0];
        var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];

        console.log(x_value)
        console.log(label)
        console.log(value)
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 1,
        onComplete: function () {
            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                    var data = dataset.data[index];
                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                });
            });
        }
    }
};

var employeeDetailsBarChart = new Chart(employeeDetailsCtx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: employee_details_data,
    options: myoption
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.