# Get bar value when onClick Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

i am faceing a problem with reactjs using chartjs
i want to get the value of Bar chart in chartjs 2 when clicking in the Bar
i found this code but i didnt know how to use it on react

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function (evt) {
    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'point', myChart.options);
    var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
    var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
    var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
    alert(label + ": " + value);
};
```

Comment: You need to add some code for us to help you.

Comment: If you would have searched for this case you would have found this one.liner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123117/11989020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, a found the answer :

```
 <Line
      data={chartData}
      options={options}
      onElementsClick={elems => {
        // if required to build the URL, you can
        // get datasetIndex and value index from an `elem`:

        var activePoint = elems[0];
        var data = activePoint._chart.data;
        var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
        var label = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
        var value = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[activePoint._index];
        alert(value);
        // and then redirect to the target page:
      }}
    />
```